# Undefined Variable error while getting value from form in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get from value from form but when calling without `isset()` and it gave me undefined Index error.

Now when I use `isset()` it gives me Undefined Variable Error.

How can i solve this?

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form action="conn.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <p>Enter Database Username:  <input type="text" name="username"></p>
        <p>Enter Password:     <input type="password" name="pass"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
    </form> 

<?php
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $username=$_POST['username'];
}

if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {
  $pass=$_POST['pass'];
}

echo($username);
echo($pass);

?>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not you make a search for result before posting question? you get more result about fixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see there are many ways to set your initial variables...but you do need to set them to echo them without warnings:

```
// Set variables to post if set, else empty if not
$username = (isset($_POST['username']))? $_POST['username']: "";
$pass     = (isset($_POST['pass']))? $_POST['pass']: "";

echo($username);
echo($pass);
```

Answer (score 2):

cause your both `$username` and `$pass` variables are not defined and not in check or `isset()` block

```
echo($username);
echo($pass);
```

initialize those variable first with blank values

```
<?php  $username='';$pass='';
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username=$_POST['username'];}
    if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];}
    echo($username);
    echo($pass);
?>
```

or make it simple by echoing in check block :-

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  echo $username=$_POST['username'];}
if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {
  echo $pass=$_POST['pass'];}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes its undefined since you're using it outside the scope of the if block that checks for the existence first.

Look closely:

```
// if this fails
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
}

// if this fails
if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
}

// your echoing an undefined variable
echo($username);
echo($pass);
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    // isset() can handle multiple parameters to check for its existence, if one of them is undefined, then its false
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    echo $username . '<br/>' . $password;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because when the form is not posted the variable will not be set.try this -

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass']
    echo($username);
    echo($pass);
}
```

or

```
$username = $pass = '';
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username=$_POST['username'];}

if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];}

echo($username);
echo($pass);
```